# AWS EC2, LINUX, NGINX, DJANGO, GUNICORN static files not found

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am currently trying to launch my Django website using Nginx and Gunicorn but my static files are not being found. I am on a Linux AMI not Ubuntu which makes things a bit harder and different because I got Nginx with

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.12
```

I was looking at these tutorials

http://www.threebms.com/index.php/2020/07/27/set-up-a-django-app-in-aws-with-gunicorn-nginx/

https://linuxtut.com/en/ce98f7afda7738c8cc1b/

but whenever I launch my website with

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myappname.wsgi
```

it always says my static files are not found....
I have already done

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

This is my config file found at. `sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
I don't really know if I should keep the first server part that was there as default but the only part that is not default is the second server but the tutorials say just add a new one to the end

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

        server {
                 listen 8000;
                 #not real address but same format
                 server_name 12.18.123.613;
                 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
                 location /static/
                        {
                         autoindex on;
                         alias /home/ec2-user/pydjangoenv/myprojname/static/;
                 }
                 location / {
                 proxy_pass http://12.18.123.613;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                 proxy_redirect off;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                 }
       }







# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
```

and the tree goes like this

```
Django-cloud9 - /home/ec2/user
  pydjangoenv
     myprojname
        blog - this is an app
        myprojname
        static
        users - this is an app
        manage.py 
        requirements.txt
  env
```

I have really been stuck on this for three days, any help is appreciated :-)

### EDIT

After adding

```
urlpatterns =+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

to my **urls.py** the Django serves the static files, but not when debug is false
the static files don't work, I really have tried everything, please help.

Comment: how you are accessing your website after running `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myappname.wsgi` you have to go to `https://your_server_ip:8000`

Comment: and try to bind like this `gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi:application- -bind 0.0.0.0:8000` and do not forget to restart your service

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yea I tried everything you suggested its still not working, its hard because I am not ubuntu so I dont know how to structure my config file