# Nginx, Django, Gunicorn, working without config file?

Tags: django, nginx

I am making a website on Django with Gunicorn, Nginx, on a Amazon Linux EC2 instance.
To deploy the website I use

```
gunicorn --worker-class gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp.wsgi
```

I am using Nginx, and everything is working the thing that is weird is that all the static files are working, without me serving them in `sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
My config file is just the default and its still working. Does Django serve static files for you through **urls.py** in

```
urlpatterns = []+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

here is my config file

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   300;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
         }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }















# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }


}
```

Comment: Check your `DEBUG` in `settings.py` if it set to `True` than **Django** will serve your static files and if it set to `False` than you have set the configuration for it.

Comment: This might be a redundant question but is your deployed app running in development mode?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari you are right my static files aren't being properly served, when debug is false...if you have time can you take a look at my post regarding this it has my config file with what I think should be in there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335938/aws-ec2-linux-nginx-django-gunicorn-static-files-not-found